# amazon dynamo db client in java- RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have an application that uses a dynamo db client, this seems to work fine most of the time but i am writing an integration test and getting this error, first it inserts fine and then the second time i go to insert i get this error.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@6145f3ae rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@380892d7[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
    at com.amazonaws.http.timers.request.HttpRequestTimer.startTimer(HttpRequestTimer.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1253)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3768)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3737)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executePutItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2419)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.putItem(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2387)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.attestation.Attestation.createEntry(Attestation.java:49)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.Subscriber.process(Subscriber.java:86)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.aws.AwsSubscriber.start(AwsSubscriber.java:88)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.SubscriberFactory.lambda$loadAwsSubscribers$0(SubscriberFactory.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

inserting like this

```
        amazonDynamoDB.putItem(itemRequest);
```

Thanks

Update - when add a try catch around and print the stack trace i get

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1134)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1080)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2147)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2116)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2105)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1559)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1530)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.aws.AwsSubscriber.start(AwsSubscriber.java:70)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.SubscriberFactory.lambda$loadAwsSubscribers$0(SubscriberFactory.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1256)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072)
    ... 14 more
2020-05-25 16:50:10.462  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-25 16:50:10.463  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-05-25 16:50:10.471  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-25 16:50:10.475  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Exception in thread "Thread-15" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: The target server failed to respond
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1134)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1080)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2147)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2116)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2105)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeReceiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1559)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.receiveMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1530)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.aws.AwsSubscriber.start(AwsSubscriber.java:70)
    at com.lmig.global.reuse.event.framework.subscriber.SubscriberFactory.lambda$loadAwsSubscribers$0(SubscriberFactory.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1256)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072)
    ... 14 more
2020-05-25 16:50:10.462  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-25 16:50:10.463  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-05-25 16:50:10.471  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-25 16:50:10.475  INFO 5530 --- [      Thread-16] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: It reached the limit of WCU ?

Comment: What is the WCU limt?

Comment: I feel this is a timeout issue, the reason being the exception thrown here.
it triggered the update data to dynamo DB but the task which triggered it is shut down before even the dynamo DB responded

Can you these

 this enable X-ray for the DynamoDB and see if the call reached DynamoDB ?
or
go to cloud trail and see if there is an event related to db query.

Comment: I am using locallstack container instances for the integration test but can take a look and see can debug that way

Answer (score 2):

below definition from AWS site:

**Write capacity unit (WCU):** Each API call to write data to your table is a write request. For items up to 1 KB in size, one WCU can perform one standard write request per second. Items larger than 1 KB require additional WCUs. Transactional write requests require two WCUs to perform one write per second for items up to 1 KB. For example, a standard write request of a 1 KB item would require one WCU, a standard write request of a 3 KB item would require three WCUs, and a transactional write request of a 3 KB item would require six WCUs.

Comment: It's strange the message I sent is fairly small in size and I did try a 3 second sleep thread before sending the second. Is there any solution you could recommend?

Comment: @AnonymousAlias
I feel this is a timeout issue , reason being the exception thrown here